# Specific Opportunity stages based on Sales Process linked to Opp. Record Types on a VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, sales-process

I have a VF page where Opp. record types shows up, I want to have the stages to be shown based on the record type selection on that VF page.

Record types have Sales Process where Opp. stages are tied up.I don't see any direct relation between sales process and the stages which can be achieved in controller.

Can anyone help me how to achieve this functionality.

Thanks

Comment: did you try using `apex:inputField`'s? With that it should automatically pull appropriate values of Stages.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code snippet : -

```
Opportunity Opts;

public Opportunity(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {  
  this.controller = controller;
  this.Opts=(Opportunity)Controller.getRecord();

   Opts.RecordTypeId = recordtypeId; //use your record type Id for which you want to show the stagevalues
}
```

While you are loading the VF page you need to forcefully assign the record type Id for which you want to show the values.

I think it will solve your purpose.